# Android Camera2 SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME issue

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm currently working on an HDR app, i'm trying to get the SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME from my preview session, to be a step in my burst session, where i change the SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME manually.

I have no issues to change my values manually, but the value i get from the preview isn't correct. There are 2 issues.

First the order of magnitude is wrong (~10k ns).
Second the value doesn't change even if i'm doing the preview on the sun or in a dark room.

Any help in understanding it would be loved.

Thanks

Gwen

Comment: Are you getting the values from the `TotalCaptureResult` item in `CaptureComplete` callback? If you are not doing that your retrieved data will be possibly wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't get that there was a TotalCaptureResult in the previewSession. It looks like i try to get my values from the wrong place. I'm trying to fix it, i'm keeping you in touch.

Comment: The SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, is a member of a request, if i understood it right. I was wrong to try to get this value from the preview request in the previewCaptureSession. Now i tried to get it from the TotalCaptureResult of the previewSession in CaptureComplete callback, this result has a request as member, where i'm supposed to find the value i want to get. I did a simple println there, to get my wanted value in every capture of the preview, the value is still the same and still wrong. I guess i understood it wrong, but i'm not getting where. Thanks for your time spent to help me.

Comment: I don't want to spam you...  TotalCaptureResult has the 'Keys' i wanted too. It's working fine now. To sum it up, i was getting the initial values, and now i get the last values when the AE mode is done.

Thank you, helped a lot to understand and make it work.

Comment: You don't spam me, dont worry about it. I didn't see this until now. camera2 api is very complex in some points, so feel free to ask me anything that you need :)